# Wrap text in a Row and if space available fill it with divider

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `Row`, which contains a Text and a expanding `Divider`. Normally the text is really short, so the divider takes a lot of the width.

```
Row (
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('some text'),
    Expanded(
      child: Divider()
    )
  ]
)
```

But sometimes the text is getting long, so it takes more then the width. In this case, it should wrap into a second line. I tried to wrap the `Text` into an `Expanded` as well, but in this case the divider takes half of the space, no matter how long the text is.

How can I achieve this behaviour (the dashes should be the divider):

```
Short Text ---------------

Loooooooooooooong Text ---

Tooooooooooooooooooo -----  // <- Divider should be vertically centered
Long Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BoxConstraints`, replace the `Container` with your divider, and you'd see it is also vertically aligned.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final text = 'Tooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Long Text  ';
  final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  final minDividerWidth = 30.0;
  final dividerHeight = 30.0;

  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: screenWidth - minDividerWidth),
            child: Text(text),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: dividerHeight,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Container(
              child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(child: new Text("A  text")),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Text('some text'),
            ],
          )),
```

OUTPUT

> When the Long text

[image]

> Using short text

[image]

Comment: Hi. I have only one text at the left. At the right there is a Divider. Its width is flexible (that's why it's wrapped into an Expanded). It should take the remaining space. This works fine, unless the Text is not too long. In that case it overflows... So question is: How to keep the behaviour of the divider by making the text wrapable